# Setting up pricing tier for free app

Tags: ios, iphone

I have developed an app which is submitted to app store already and also approved. But I have following questions in my mind.

1. Currently my app is free. But my client wants to make it paid after
   2    months. I did not set pricing information because not yet
   confirmed    which tier want to select. So my question is if I set
   pricing    information after some days of my app approval, does app
   will go for    review again? Changing pricing information needs
   approval?
2. Suppose one of the user downloaded app on his device when app is
   free. Client changed pricing details and now app is not free. Now my
   question is how that user will do payment procedure. Does apple
   handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are answers of your question.

1. No, your app will not go to review again for price change. Your app simply become paid app.
2. If user has downloaded your app when it was free, then he/she can use your app all the time. Even if after 2 months, if you make your app as paid, then existing users need not to pay for that, because they have already downloaded app when it was free. Only new user has to paid to download app.

Hope, you got an idea of your question.

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

1. Currently my app is free. But my client wants to make it paid after 2 months. I did not set pricing    information because not yet confirmed which tier want to select. So my question is
   if I set pricing information after some days of my app approval, does app will go for review again? Changing pricing information needs approval ?.

   **NO. Unless you make some changes in your app and you want to upload a new version or something. Just a price change doesn't required a reapproval**
2. Suppose one of the user downloaded app on his device when app is
   free. Client changed pricing details and now app is not free. Now my question is how that user will do payment procedure. Does apple handle this scenario ?.

   **No apple won't handle this scenario. They'll continue to use it as free. Apple says App you once buy/download is yours. And all the updates which comes later are free.**

Answer (score 1):

1. No, changing price doesn't require another review
2. Once the app is downloaded the user has it they do not pay again.